# If a code $C$ receives a codeword $\mathbf{u}$ as an error, but $\mathbf{u}$ is a valid codeword, will $C$ ever detect the error?

Tags: coding-theory

This is a problem I'm reading in the document *Introduction to Algebraic Coding Theory* by Sarah Spence Adams. Problem 1.7 states

> Let $C$ be a code that contains $\mathbf{0}$, the codeword consisting of a string of all zeros. Suppose that $C$ contains a string $\mathbf{u}$ as a codeword. Now suppose that the string $\mathbf{u}$ also occurs as an error. Prove that $C$ will not always detect when the error $\mathbf{u}$ occurs.

I suppose a codeword $\mathbf{c}$ is sent, but the codeword $\mathbf{u}$ is received instead due to some errors. So far, codes attempt to correct errors by reinterpreting them as a nearest codeword under the Hamming distance $d$, regardless if this is correct or not. But if $\mathbf{u}$ is also a codeword in $C$, then $d(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u})=0$, so it seems to me the received error will just be interpreted as the correct receipt of $\mathbf{u}$, so will never be detected as an error.

But I am skeptical because the wording of the problem makes it seem like $C$ may occasionally detect $\mathbf{u}$ as an error, and I also make no use of the fact that $\mathbf{0}\in C$. Am I interpreting this wrongly?

Comment: I think you're right; if a codeword is recieved, it is impossible to detect that there has been an error. And it doesn't matter whether the zero string is a codeword or not.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I believe it is not saying that the codeword $\mathbf{u}$ is received in error; but rather that $\mathbf{u}$ **is** the error, so if $\mathbf{c}$ is sent then $\mathbf{c}+\mathbf{u}$ is received (in which case the fact that $\mathbf{0}$ is a codeword means that this can result in $\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{u}$ received when $\mathbf{0}$ is sent).

Comment: @Morgan OP writes "the codeword $u$ is received instead due to some errors." I don't see how to interpret this as saying that $u$ is the error. How can you say "$c+u$ is received", when OP clearly states "$u$ is received"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am referring to what the problem is asking about: "Suppose that the string $\mathbf{u}$ also occurs as an error," this is is referring to $\mathbf{u}$ **being** the error, not being the word received after an error is applied to the sent codeword (as described in Dilip's answer, the string $\mathbf{u}$ is the error pattern).

Comment: @Morgan yes, I should rely on what the book says more than on what OP thinks it means.

Comment: Yes, it seems I interpreted it incorrectly, thanks @MorganRodgers for clarifying the correct meaning of the problem statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general model in coding theory says that $x$, what is transmitted over the channel, is a codeword, that is, an element of the code $\mathcal C$, while what is received is $y = x+e$ where $e$ is called the error pattern or error vector or error word. The receiver then *estimates* what the most likely transmitted codeword is given that $y$ has been received. If $\hat{x}$ denotes the estimate of the most likely transmitted codeword, then the receiver effectively has also *estimated* that the error pattern is $\hat{e} = y-\hat{x}$. If $\hat{x}$ does in fact *equal* $x$, then the receiver estimate is correct, and also the estimated error pattern $\hat{e}$ is the same as the error $e$ that actually occurred. If $\hat{x} \neq x$, then the receiver's estimate of $x$ is incorrect, and so is the receiver's estimate of $e$. What is *not* incorrect is the receiver's conclusion that errors *did* occur.

So, what happens when the channel is unusually cooperative and *makes no errors at all?* Well, the channel output $y$ equals $x$ and when the receiver tests $y$ and finds that it is a valid codeword, it accepts $x$ (sets $\hat{x} = x$) and thus estimates that no errors have occurred. What if the channel output $y$ is some codeword $x^\prime$ *other* than the transmitted codeword $x$? Note that $y=x+e = x^\prime$ where $e$ is necessarily a nonzero vector. Well, the receiver tests $y$, finds that it is a valid codeword $x^\prime$, and sets $\hat{x}$ to $x^\prime$, estimating that *no errors occurred* during transmission whereas in fact errors *did* occur. The receiver thus is *unable* to detect the error pattern $x^\prime - x$ where $x, x^\prime \in \mathcal C$ are two distinct codewords; more generally, the receiver is unable to detect *any* error pattern that is the *difference* of two distinct codewords. If the all-zeroes vector $\mathbf 0 \in \mathcal C$, then the previous sentence says that, in particular, the receiver cannot detect any error pattern that *equals* a nonzero codeword.